# Openssl RSA key size

Tags: ssl, openssl, key

I've generated an RSA key by this command:

```
openssl genpkey -algorithm RSA -out private_key.pem -pkeyopt rsa_keygen_bits:2048
```

I exported the key to DER format, which is the binary form. The key is a waaay more than 2k bits. For test, I exported the public key to DER format, which is slightly more than 2k bits.

So the question, what is 2048 bits? How can I get the raw bits from the generated file?

Thanks,
Lev

Comment: Where you want to get your raw bits? Which language or tool you want to use?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Information Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: I want to write the key to a FLASH of a CPU. The CPU will use the key to encrypt/decrypt messages, and send it through wireless interface.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to encrypt and decrypt using a RSA key, you need the modulus, the private and public exponent.

Usually encryption is performed using the couple (modulus, public exponent) and decryption using the couple (modulus, private exponent).

Now on some implementations, like often on embedded device, the public exponent is set per default to the number called F4, which is 0x10001 or 65537 decimal.

With a 2048 bits RSA key, the private exponent is exactly 2048 bits, as well as the modulus.

You can get the private exponent in binary format by doing some string manipulation:

```
openssl rsa -in key.der -inform der -text -noout | awk '/^[^ ]/{if($1 == "privateExponent:") {dump=1} else {dump=0}} /^ /{if(dump==1){gsub(":","");printf "%s", $1}}END{print ""}' | xxd -ps -r -c256 > pr_key.bin
```

You can also get the modulus by replacing the string in the awk command.

In resume, to store your 2048 bits private key, you'll need 4096 bits (512 bytes). To store the public key, you'll need 2048 bits (256 bytes).

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. However, it turned out that library we are using needs the DER format, which is easy to generate. Standing stupid, and sorry for the noise.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT 3 / 4:**

I haven't found a convinient way to do that. Anyway, you might try the following:

`openssl rsa -in <yourfile> -noout -text`

It will display more information about the private key. Check [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) for how to calculate the keys with the given information.

**Old Solution (doesn't work, so ignore it)**

For an automated process or just simply for educational purpose?

A manual approach could be the following (assuming you're a linux user):

- Make a copy of the key file
- Open your pem file with vi(m) and remove the first and last line (BEGIN/END PRIVATE KEY)
- Remove the line breaks (e.g. :%s/\n//g)
- Save the file
- Now base64 decode the file (base64 -d `[your file name here] > [destination]`)

But most likely openssl provides a more convinient way to achieve this goal

**EDIT 1:**

This could be wrong in case that pem / der stores additional information besides the key.

**EDIT 2:**

Besides I've never seen a reason to extract the private key yet (or to even generate one in the way you do).

What is the goal you want to achieve?

Comment: *"Remove the line breaks..."* - If you remove the line breaks for the pre- and post encapsulation headers (`-----BEGIN X-----` and `-----END X-----`), then the key may not be parsed and you could get the ***`PEM_read_bio:no start...`*** error.

Comment: Exactly, that's why to first step is to make a copy of the key;) so we still have a correct pem file to work with later.

Comment: Doing this will give the same result if I use the DER format. Still not 2048bits. I want to store the key in an MCU's memory.

Comment: @Lev I've updated the answer. It should work with some effort. I think there must be an easier way but wasn't able to find one.